# Keyboard event propagation in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-events

I have a user control. Within the user control, there is a PictureBox that uses up the entire screen estate (Dock.Fill). I would like to catch keyboard events (e.g., Ctrl-V for implementing Paste functionality).

However, the PictureBox does not have any key events. Will the next layer under the PictureBox (i.e. the user control) get the KeyUp event? If I add my KeyUp event handler to the user control, will that work? I know that WPF has the solution of routed events. How does that work in winforms world?

Comment: PictureBox will not take the focus.  So yes, the UserControl gets the messages.  Avoid making keyboard handling of a user control the responsibility of the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can receive the event in the form. See [Form.KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx).

> When this property is set to true, the form will receive all KeyPress, KeyDown, and KeyUp events. After the form's event handlers have completed processing the keystroke, the keystroke is then assigned to the control with focus

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MouseUp, MouseEnter, MouseDown or MouseHover ....`

Link about Mouse Down : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown.aspx

Link  : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx

Comment: Mouse is no problem. I had issues with the keyboard events.