# Get KeyCode value in the KeyPress event

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

How to fix this error:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs' does not contain a definition
>   for 'KeyCode' and no extension method 'KeyCode' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Enter Key Pressed ");
     }
}
```

I'm using Visual studio 2010, framework 4 for this project.

Comment: Here you go: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't get `KeyCode` from `KeyPress`(at least without using some mapping) event because [KeyPressEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar(v=vs.110).aspx) provide only the [KeyChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

But you can get it from the [`KeyDown` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx). `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs` has the required `KeyCode` property:

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString());
    }
```

---

If the KeyDown event doesn't suit you, you can still save the KeyCode in some private field and use it later in the KeyPress event, because under normal circumstances each KeyPress is preceeded by KeyDown:

> Key events occur in the following order:
>
> - KeyDown
> - KeyPress
> - KeyUp

```
private Keys m_keyCode;

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    this.m_keyCode = e.KeyCode;
}

private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (this.m_keyCode == Keys.Enter)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Enter Key Pressed ");
     }
}
```

Comment: Another error: `No overload for 'Form1_KeyPress' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler' `

Comment: @Smygolas You have to remove the old handler `Form1_KeyPress` (manually or from the Form Properties in the editor) and then add a new handler for `Form1_KeyDown`

Comment: Another error: `The type or namespace name 'KeyCode' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @Smygolas Sorry, it is actually `Keys `. And in your scenario you, perhaps, can use only the `KeyDown` event without the private field.

Comment: It doesn't work, I press enter but messagebox dont show

Comment: Are you sure that you added Form1_KeyDown and Form1_KeyPress as handlers for the appropriate events? And make sure that the form itself is focused and not some input control.

Comment: Add as hanglers like this:`this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
            this.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyPress);`

Comment: @Smygolas I do not know what the problem is. It works perfectly on my machine with clean form. Try to put breakpoints inside the handlers and check whether they are executed at all.

Comment: I think problem is because I'm using WebBrowser() who is navigate to flashplayer.

Comment: Then you have to set these handlers for your webbrowser too. Or just use answer from this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639673/keyboard-event-propagation-in-winforms

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    private void game_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            MessageBox.Show(Keys.Enter.ToString(), "information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```